# PHP Multi Dimensional Array Extract

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

im trying to create simple array from foreach loop

```
function ptd_get_taxanomies(){
            foreach ($ptd_taxs as $ptd_tax) {
                $taxon_arg[] = array(
                    'taxonomy' =>$ptd_tax->taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $values
                );
            }
    return $taxon_arg;
}
```

, but it returns me multidimensional array,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [taxonomy] => application
            [field] => id
            [terms] => 8

        )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [taxonomy] => dimension
        [field] => id
        [terms] => 4

    )

);
```

but this is not that i want, i need an output like this >

```
   array(
    'taxonomy' => 'application',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => '8',
   ),
   array(
    'taxonomy' => 'dimension',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => '4',
  )
```

how do i remove the first level array and get the output like above

Comment: That's what you've got. You have two arrays, which you want to return. You can only return one value, so you have to return an array containing those arrays. That's how it works.

Comment: The second one is also a 2 dimensional array, all you leave is the surrounding block in your output. Or else, can you please clarify of what you would like to achieve (get done)?

Answer (score 3):

```
function ptd_get_taxanomies(){
    foreach ($ptd_taxs as $ptd_tax) {
        $taxon_arg = $ptd_tax;            
    }
    return $taxon_arg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the result?

```
$taxon_arg =ptd_get_taxanomies();

foreach($taxon_arg as $arg){
    var_dump($arg);
}
```